# C# - How to reload page with new parameter in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, onclick

I have a Hyperlink in my View with text dependent to code behind:

```
<a href="http://somelink"> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Link) </a>
```

in my Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Link")]
public string Link { get; set; }
```

And in my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    Models.Home DLink = new Models.Home();
    DLink.Link = id;
    return View(DLink);
}
```

As expected, I can change Hyperlink description `http://localhost:61227/Home/Index/hyperlinkdescription`
Now my problem is: I CAN NOT change Hyperlink description using button `onclick` like this:

```
<button class="but-lay" id="but-id" type="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {id = "something" })'" >Button</button>
```

This button is located in the same `view` of Hyperlink & controller.

**UPDATE:** If I use `type="button"` for that button Problem will be solved, BUT user may use Enter key instead of pressing button.

Comment: Why does that button have `type="submit"`? That should be `type="button"`

Comment: button  solves the problem but user should have the option to use enter instead of clicking

Comment: Well, then you need to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: Unrelated but moving forward I'd not recommend using `onclick=` and use javascript instead because it can get real messy and weird.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller

```
//namespace Testy20161006.Controllers
public class ReloadPageViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ToIndex()
    {
        //put a breakpoint here to go to this action,
        //after url change
        ReloadPageViewModel DLink = new ReloadPageViewModel();
        DLink.Link = "http://somelink";
        return View(DLink);
    }

    public ActionResult Tut116()
    {
        ViewBag.MyURL = "http://www.Google.com";
        ReloadPageViewModel DLink = new ReloadPageViewModel();
        //don't show you this property, I concentrate on your main problem,
        //which is, how a button click, can change href
        DLink.Link = "6";
        return View(DLink);
    }
```

Your view

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@model Testy20161006.Controllers.ReloadPageViewModel
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut116</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#but-id").click(function () {
                $("a").text("to home index")
                $("a").attr("href", "/Home/ToIndex/")
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a id="theLink" href="@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode(ViewBag.MyURL))"
           title="@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode(ViewBag.MyURL))">
            google
        </a>
        <button class="but-lay" id="but-id" type="button">
            Change HREF of link Button
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add this   $(document).bind('keypress', function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        $("#but-id").trigger('click');
                        return false;
                    }
                });

Comment: This last comment solved my problem. Just I had to add it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Layout.cshtml page SET the ROOT

```
<script>
    var ROOT = '@Url.Content("~/")';
</script>
```

Now Give a id to `<a id="hreflink"></a>`. On button click write the below script

```
$('#hreflink').each(function () {
                var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
                var url = ROOT + "new link?id1=" + value1+ '&id2=' + value2;
                $(this).attr("href", url); // Set herf value
            });
```

you are good to go .